# How to use argparse IP address and community string?

Tags: python, network-programming, argparse

The title pretty much summarizes what I'd like to have happen.

I want to execute a python script that does something with IP address and community string.

I use the following command for parsing:

```
import argparse

def get_args():
    '''This function parses and return arguments passed in'''
    # Assign description to the help doc
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='')
    # Add arguments
    parser.add_argument(
        '-i', '--ip-adress', type=str, help='ip address of the host', required=True)
    parser.add_argument(
        '-c', '--community', type=str, help='community string', required=True)
    # Array for all arguments passed to script
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # Assign args to variables
    IP = args.ip-adress
    COMMUNITY = args.community
    # Return all variable values
    return IP ,COMMUNITY

# Run get_args()
# get_args()
# Match return values from get_arguments()
# and assign to their respective variables
IP , COMMUNITY = get_args()

# Print the values

print "\n ip address : [ %s ]\n" % IP
print "\ncommunity: [ %s ]\n" % COMMUNITY
```

However, no matter how I played with the argument I cannot figure out why I get this error.

```
python arg.py -i 10.0.1.2 -c xxbsd

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "arg.py", line 30, in <module>
    IP , COMMUNITY = get_args()
  File "arg.py", line 20, in get_args
    IP = args.ip-adress
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'ip'
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: It's a good idea to `print(args)` during debugging.  Do that before trying to use attributes of `args`.  It should help you avoid a lot of fruitless playing.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `args.ip-adress` you should use `args.ip_adress`.

**EDITED:**

the `-` symbol is subtraction and may not be used in variable names. argparse will translate it to the variable `args.ip_address`, so use that and you'll be golden

Comment: This is your answer.  the `-` symbol is subtraction and may not be used in variable names.  `argparse` will translate it to the variable `args.ip_address`, so use that and you'll be golden.

Comment: @UtahJarhead thank you! I have added this to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't use the dash in the variable name, because Python will interpret it as `args.ip minus adress`.

You can change the variable name to `args.ipaddress` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

To have complete control on the variable names you can specify your own name

```
parser.add_argument(... dest=my_var ...)
```